# Populate input boxes based on the clicked/scrolled row in table

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I need your help.

With the help of existing javascript experts, I was able to create a table where a user could scoll to (using their up and down arrow keys) as well as to allow a user click on a row to select and highlight it.

Now comes time where i'd like to modify my existing function such that, whenever the user clicks on or uses their arrow keys to navigate to the selected row in the table, id like to pull the information (data) from the row and use it to populate the list of input boxes below. How could the javascript coding be modified so as to allow me to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#mstrTable tr.normal td {
    color: #235A81;
    background-color: white;
}
#mstrTable tr.highlighted td {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #235A81;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function test() {

var table = document.getElementById("mstrTable");
var thead = table.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var ishigh;

tbody.onclick = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var td = e.target || e.srcElement
  var row = td.parentNode;
  if (ishigh&&ishigh!=row){
    ishigh.className='';
  }
  row.className = row.className==="highlighted" ? "" : "highlighted";
  ishigh=row;
}

document.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e || event;
    var code = e.keyCode, rowslim = table.rows.length - 2, newhigh;
    if(code === 38){ //up arraow
        newhigh = rowindex(ishigh) - 2;
        if(!ishigh || newhigh < 0){return GoTo('mstrTable', rowslim);}
        return GoTo('mstrTable', newhigh);
    } else if (code === 40){ //down arrow
        newhigh = rowindex(ishigh);
        if(!ishigh || newhigh > rowslim){return GoTo('mstrTable', 0);}
        return GoTo('mstrTable', newhigh);
    }
}

function GoTo(id,nu){
  var obj=document.getElementById(id),
      trs=obj.getElementsByTagName('TR');
  nu = nu + 1;
  if (trs[nu]){
    if (ishigh&&ishigh!=trs[nu]){
      ishigh.className='';
    }
    trs[nu].className = trs[nu].className=="highlighted" ? "" : "highlighted";
    ishigh=trs[nu];
   }
}

function rowindex(row){
    var rows = table.rows, i = rows.length;
    while(--i > -1){
        if(rows[i] === row){return i;}
    }
}

}//end of nested function

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <table id="mstrTable" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>first name</th>
            <th>last name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>total</th>
            <th>discount</th>
            <th>diff</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>peter</td>
            <td>parker</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>9.99</td>
            <td>20.3%</td>
            <td>+3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>john</td>
            <td>hood</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>19.99</td>
            <td>25.1%</td>
            <td>-7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>clark</td>
            <td>kent</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>15.89</td>
            <td>44.2%</td>
            <td>-15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bruce</td>
            <td>almighty</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>153.19</td>
            <td>44%</td>
            <td>+19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bruce</td>
            <td>evans</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>153.19</td>
            <td>23%</td>
            <td>+9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
Firstname is:
<input type="text" id="firstname" />
<br>Lastname is:
<input type="text" id="lastname" />
<br>Age is:
<input type="text" id="age" />
<br>Total is:
<input type="text" id="total" />
<br>Discount is:
<input type="text" id="discount" />
<br>Diff is:
<input type="text" id="diff" />

<br>
<input type="button" value="testme" onclick="test()">
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write another function to populate necessary fields. Example:

```
function populateFields(row) {
    el('firstname').value = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
    el('lastname').value = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
    el('age').value = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
    el('total').value = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
    el('discount').value = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
    el('diff').value = row.cells[5].innerHTML;
}
// el() is shortcut for document.getElementById
```

Where you pass corresponding row to the function to get data from.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/HDu8n/

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much. I hope to be familiarized completely with javascript and DOM. Most of my js is self taught. I have a long ways to go.